# How to change the styles of a toggle button, defined in the app.css when button is clicked? When clicked again it should change back to white mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// this is app.js    

import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    
    function App() {
      return (<>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="inside">
            <button id="button" onClick={change}></button> //this is a button which wrapped in a div element.
          </div>
        </div>
      </>);
    }
    
    export default App;
```

We have a button. [When button is clicked it will change its position to the right and dark colour should be applied. When clicked again, the button should switch to the left position and it should change back to white mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4M1y.png)

```
//this is app.css

    #inside{
      width:156px;
      display: flex;
      height:49px;
      border:7px solid yellowgreen; // it should changed to 7px solid black when button clicked.
      border-radius: 50px;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:flex-start; // i want to change this to flex-end when button clicked.
    }
    #container{
      display:flex;
      height:100vh;
      border:1px solid black;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: black; //when button clicked it should be changed to yellow color.
    }
    #button{
      display:flex;
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 30px;
      height:45px;
      width:56px;
    }
```

Comment: Use a boolean state variable and toggle it. Then add/remove a class to <body> and write a stylesheet that changes the properties based on the class: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-buck-ljd0oc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is just one way, the other is to pass `style` props to the components that change the style directly based on the state.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a .active class, and a state for toggling active status:

In your App.js

```
function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const change = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="container" className={`${active && 'active'}`}>
        <div id="inside" className={`${active && 'active'}`}>
          <button id="button" onClick={change}></button> //this is a button
          which wrapped in a div element.
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

In your app.css

```
#inside {
  width: 156px;
  display: flex;
  height: 49px;
  /* it should changed to 7px solid black when button clicked. */
  border: 7px solid yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  /* i want to change this to flex-end when button clicked. */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* //when button clicked it should be changed to yellow color. */
  background-color: black;
}

#button {
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 56px;
}

#container.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container.active #inside {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: app.js=> className={`${active && 'active'}`}   app.css=>#container.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}  active is true when button clicked but in `${active && 'active'}` what is 'active'? you are comparing active which is true and what is 'active' here?

Comment: It's just my habbit of using Short-circuit evaluation. You may want to read it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#:~:text=Short%2Dcircuit%20evaluation). It's like this: if the active is true then `active && 'active'` return 'active' else it will return false and className will be empty.